# Does MySql's HEX() return any other characters other than alphanumeric?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing `HEX(aes_encrypt('my data'),'key')` in a script of mine, and was wondering if HEX() returns data other than alphanumeric?

Does HEX() return special characters or anything other than alphanumeric data?

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation states:

> [Hex()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) - 
>   For a string argument str, HEX() returns a hexadecimal string
>   representation of str where each character in str is converted to two
>   hexadecimal digits. The inverse of this operation is performed by the
>   UNHEX() function.

I would say the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No - it returns only pairs of hexadecimal characters, ie characters from the set: `0123456789ABCDEF`